# Exporting Excel is giving error on button click

Tags: asp.net, excel, gridview

I am implementing the functionality that on button click the data saved in the gridview should get exported on the button click, I implemented the functionality from [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-to-Excel-in-ASPNet-with-Formatting-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx).

But I am getting error as *Control 'mainContent_grdTeacherProfile' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server*  at line

```
grdTeacherProfile.RenderControl(hw);
```

Please see the asps code of the gridview:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdTeacherProfile"
                runat="server"
                Width="100%"
                border="1" Style="border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;"
                CellPadding="3" FooterStyle-BackColor="#e3e3e3"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                AllowPaging="true"
                CssClass="hoverTable"
                DataKeyNames="Id"
                PageSize="4"
                ShowFooter="false"
                OnPreRender="PreRenderGrid"
                HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td"
                OnDataBound="grdTeacherProfile_DataBound"
                OnPageIndexChanging="grdTeacherProfile_PageIndexChanging"
                OnRowDeleting="grdTeacherProfile_RowDeleting"
                OnRowCommand="grdTeacherProfile_RowCommand"
                EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false"
                EmptyDataText="No records found">
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="k-alt" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-Width="5" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" onClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="first_name" HeaderText="First Name" ItemStyle-Width="30"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="last_name" HeaderText="Last Name" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="dob" HeaderText="Date of Birth" ItemStyle-Width="20"  ApplyFormatInEditMode="true" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="gender" HeaderText="Gender" ItemStyle-Width="20"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="designation" HeaderText="Designation" ItemStyle-Width="20" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="joining_date" HeaderText="Joining Date" ItemStyle-Width="20"  ApplyFormatInEditMode="true" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="leaving_date" HeaderText="Leaving Date" ItemStyle-Width="20"  ApplyFormatInEditMode="true" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="active" HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-Width="25" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="5%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" AlternateText="Edit" ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" CommandName="eEdit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CausesValidation="false" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" AlternateText="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <PagerStyle ForeColor="#e3e3e3"
                    BackColor="#e3e3e3" CssClass="grid-pagi" />
                <PagerTemplate>
                <table runat="server" id="testTable1" style="width: 100%" class="hoverTable_tbl">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-4 pull-left">
                            <asp:Label ID="MessageLabel"
                                Text="Select a page:"
                                runat="server" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="FirstLB" runat="server" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="First" ToolTip="First" CssClass="btn-pager btn-default"><<</asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="PrevLB" runat="server" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev" ToolTip="Previous" CssClass="btn-pager btn-default"><</asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="PageDropDownList" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="PageDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="selectpicker form-control-drp"></asp:DropDownList>

                            <asp:LinkButton ID="NextLB" runat="server" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" ToolTip="Next" CssClass="btn-pager btn-default">></asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LastLB" runat="server" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Last" ToolTip="Last" CssClass="btn-pager btn-default">>></asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-3">
                            <div>
                            <div class="pull-left"><asp:Label ID="PageSizeLabel" CssClass="page-size" runat="server" Text="Select Page Size: "></asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPageSize" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="selectpicker form-control-drp">
                                <%-- <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="0" />--%>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1" />
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2" />
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="3" />
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            <div> 
                                 <asp:Label ID="CurrentPageLabel" CssClass="view" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </PagerTemplate>

                <RowStyle />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it done on my own,

actually I forgot to add the code below and `EnableEventValidation="false"`.

The code was:-

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
    }
```

and it worked.!!

Answer (score 1):

Exporting GridView to Excel is easier using a 3rd party like iTextSharp.

If you want to know how I make it work, you can check this sample code:

http://dotnetfrommanila.blogspot.com/2013/04/convert-gridview-to-excel-in-c.html

I hope it could help you.

Comment: I am not getting the `namespace` in my VS , why like `using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;`

Comment: You need to add iTextSharp in your application. If you have NuGet installed, In VS, just go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution, then search for iTextSharp

Comment: I installed the `iTextSharp` , Now What I have to do ??

Comment: I am getting error as `Cells canno be used as Method`. at `grdTeacherProfile.HeaderRow.Cells(0).Style.Add("background-color", "yellow");`